# Javascript plugin has to be disabled after updating to phpstorm 7.1.1

Tags: javascript, plugins, upgrade, phpstorm

I recently updated to PHPStorm 7.1.1 (from 7.0.0) on Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm getting the following error message (excerpt):

```
Plugin 'JavaScript' failed to initialize and will be disabled.  Please restart PhpStorm.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.webcore.libraries.ScriptingLibraryManager.(Lcom/intellij/openapi/project/Project;Lcom/intellij/openapi/roots/libraries/LibraryType;)V
[...]
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your installation is broken. Did you extract the installation package into the empty folder, or over some existing installation? Please open directory "/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/lib/" - what files can you see their? Seems that the folder contains some outdated jar files
Anyway, the solution is to remove the installation and reinstall from scratch into the *empty* folder

Comment: Thanks! Forgot to delete the phpstorm folder.